spray foamed attic floor now replacing flex duct
The duct work in our attic needs to be replaced.
When the house was built 20 years ago the attic floor was spray foamed. The flex duct work now needs to be replaced what is the best solution.
Should the flex be patched above the foam - thus not disturbing the original foam?
If it is patched, should that 3 ft section from the original foam to the past the patch be foamed?

The duct lines are currently embedded in the spray foam?

Cut it out, including some foam. Replace it. Foam around the new duct to patch when done.
I mean, honestly, the best solution is not to use flex duct, because rigid duct flows air with less friction, and is more durable; but if you "need to replace the flex duct" then leaving bits of the old flex duct doesn't seem like a good idea as there must be some (unstated) reason it's being replaced, such as it's deteriorated with 20 years of age.
